# I need to execute a thread at intervals that can change and is being dynamically changed by another thread

Tags: java, multithreading

I need to executable a Runnable implementation at intervals of time that can keep changing and is adjusted by another thread. Can I achieve this using SchedulerExecutorService and ScheduleWithFixedDelay ? Will doing this:

```
    ThreadScheduler = backgroundExecutors.scheduleWithFixedDelay(refreshFunc, 5, refreshRate, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

check the value of the variable refreshRate and adapt accordingly ?

I do not want to put the thread on sleep via a variable like this :

```
    Thread.sleep(variable);
```

I would be thankful to anyone who can provide some useful information here.

EDIT: 
I will rephrase my question. If I have to change the time interval associated with scheduleWithFixedDelay, is it possible when the task execution is progress.

EDIT 2:

```
ScheduledExecutorService scheduledExecutorService = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(5);      
   ScheduledFuture scheduledFuture;      
   Runnable foo = new Runnable() {         
       public void run() {             
           doSomething();        
       }     
   }      
   while (true) {        
       scheduledFuture = scheduledExecutorService.schedule(foo, refreshRate, TimeUnit.SECONDS);       
       scheduleFuture.cancel();     
}
```

Please note that refreshRate keeps changing. Will this work ?

EDIT 3:

```
ScheduledExecutorService scheduleExecutorService = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(5);
ScheduleFuture scheduledFuture;
Runnable foo = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        doSomething();
    }
    scheduledFuture.cancel():
    scheduleFuture = scheduledExecutorService.schedule(foo, refreshRate, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}
scheduleFuture = scheduledExecutorService.schedule(foo, refreshRate, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
enter code here
```

So is this what you are suggesting ?

Comment: You can schedule the next task from the task itself

Comment: Take the `Future` returned by the `scheduleXXX` operation, and `cancel()` it. Now schedule a new task with the new interval.

Comment: Please check my edit above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`scheduleWithFixedDelay(Runnable command, long initialDelay, long delay, TimeUnit unit)` gives you, as the name hints, a fixed delay between executions. The interval between executions is fixed by the parameter `delay`.  Once scheduled, it's not possible to change the scheduling parameters. You would need to cancel the `scheduledFuture` and issue a new command.

If your scheduling time between runs is variable, an option will be to read the next execution time at the end of your job run and let it schedule a new execution using: `schedule(Runnable command, long newDelay, TimeUnit unit)`

Comment: Essentially what you are suggesting is this :
    `ScheduledExecutorService scheduledExecutorService =
        Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(5);

    ScheduledFuture scheduledFuture;

    Runnable foo = new Runnable() { 
       public void run() { 
           doSomething();
       }
    }

    while (true) { 
      scheduledFuture = scheduledExecutorService.schedule(foo, refreshRate, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
      scheduleFuture.cancel();
    }`

Please note that `refreshRate` keeps changing.

Comment: please check my EDIT 2 above.

Comment: @rajath26 No. Roughly something like this: ReschedulingRunnable implements Runnable { public void run() { ...do stuff ...; long nextDelay = TimeKeeper.getDelay(); schedule(new ReschedulinngRunnable(), nextDelay, timeunit); }.

Comment: @rajath no need for a `while(true)`

Comment: check EDIT3. Is that what you are suggesting ? Will it work ?

Comment: I would suggest to try it out. You got the idea now.